# How to change date format value in filter text DC.JS

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

How to change date format value inside

`range: <span class="filter"></span>`

to full date format

[image: image explanation]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! That image is completely unnecessary for the question you are asking. Why not just include examples and/or format strings that illustrate your desired date formats _as plain text_ directly into the question? Also, this is a very common task for which you will easily find an answer by searching for existing Q&A's on Stack Overflow. Good luck!

Comment: .filterPrinter maybe?

Comment: Beg to differ - the image explains everything. You made two mistakes in the eyes of the grumps around here: 1. put your question in words 2. avoid the javascript tag like the plague because it will just bring haters. Wow, summer of love where r u now?

Comment: And yeah, [filterPrinter](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#filterPrinter__anchor) plus [d3.timeFormat](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#timeFormat) should do it. Please try them out and edit your question if you can't get them to work!

Comment: Good god. The Javascript tag community is a real piece of work...

Comment: then, next time maybe i should using jQuery tag...

Answer (score 1):

```
chart.filterPrinter(function(filters) {
        var dateStart = new Date(dc.utils.printSingleValue(filters[0][0]));
        var dateEnd = new Date(dc.utils.printSingleValue(filters[0][1]));
        var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%d-%B-%Y");         
          return formatTime(dateStart) +
            ' to ' + formatTime(dateEnd);
        });
```

thanks to the community :)